# Heroku - How do I prevent this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have made a game called kotakio (with nodejs), and have it hosted on kotakio.herokuapp.com, I now have a custom domain name, under kotak.io, but when I try and go on it, it says that my connection isn't secure, I think this is because it uses the certificate for *.herokuapp.com, as it says that the server may be trying to trick me. Is there a way for me to prevent this without having to buy the SSL Endpoint addon, as it's 20$/month, and this is only a hobby project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use hobby or professional dynos you could try the [beta for default ssl encryption](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours#heroku-ssl-encryption-as-the-default) with no additional charges. Otherwise the only way to use custom domains with ssl without that warning is adding the addon...